# Quickstart, karate-archetype. Getting an error when running UsersRunner.java using Karate Runner

Tags: karate

In the default karate-archetype and using Karate Runner on VSCode in Windows. I was getting an error when running UsersRunner.java

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: not found: examples/users/c:\karatedemo\myproject\src\test\java\examples\users\users.feature
```

with

```
class UsersRunner {

@Karate.Test
Karate testUsers() {
    return Karate.run("users").relativeTo(getClass());
}
```

However, I resolved it by using `return Karate.run("classpath:examples")` instead. Why is that? It may be pretty basic, but I'm quite new to this so thanks for the help in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be a bug, or that the `@Karate.Test` annotation is designed for Java IDE-s and not really VS Code, which can directly run feature files without a JUnit runner.

As you already figured out, you can change the `UsersRunner` code:

```
return Karate.run("classpath:examples/users.feature");
```